# Segmentation fault when odbc_fetch special characters on CLI only

Tags: php, mysql, db2

I'm working on a debian server with php 7.0. My php code gets data using an odbc connection and then push them in another mysql database.

When I'm running my php script in a browser, there is no issue. When I'm running it in CLI, I get a segmentation fault at the "odbc_fetch_array" line when a data with special characters comes. I don't understand where does the problem come from.
Thanks for your help

DB2 Data base example [id, name]:

```
Line 1 : [1,John]   //will work
Line 2 : [2,Stéphanie]  //will fail
```

Phy Script :

```
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$strQuery);

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $strSqlInsert = 'INSERT into....VALUES($row->name,.....)';
    $rConnexionDwh->exec($strSqlInsert);
    unset($row);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the lines of code that are crashing , and post which Db2-client you are using (and its version), and details of the result-set being fetched (columns, data-types, lengths).

Comment: Please give the requested DB2-client details and its version/fixpack. Also give the value of $LANG on debian for the account(s) that run PHP, and the codepage/codeset/territory of the DB2 database.